# Horizontally and vertically centered image within a circle within another circle in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to accomplish something that looks like this, using Bootstrap 4 and css:

[image]

What I have so far is this css:

```
.inner-circle {
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;

    -moz-border-radius: 50%; /* or 50% */
    border-radius: 50%; /* or 50% */

    background-color: #d2e4ff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.outer-circle {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;

    -moz-border-radius: 50%; /* or 50% */
    border-radius: 50%; /* or 50% */

    background-color: #e7f1ff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

and then this html:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row" class="h-100">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 h-100">
                        <span class="outer-circle mx-auto my-auto">
                            <span class="inner-circle mx-auto my-auto">
                                <img src="images/breakfast.svg" height="40" width="40" />
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 my-auto">
                        <h4 class="display5">Cool stuff</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That gets me here:

[image]

Which is not quite what I want. I have been unsuccessful with trying to get the image centered within the inner circle and then the inner circle centered within the outer circle. Is this something that is easily achievable, or should I just try to make the whole thing as an image and then just insert that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex to center align vertically and horizontally.

```css
.inner-circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d2e4ff;
}

.outer-circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e7f1ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row" class="h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-2 h-100">
          <span class="outer-circle mx-auto my-auto">
                            <span class="inner-circle mx-auto my-auto">
                                A
                            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 my-auto">
          <h4 class="display5">Cool stuff</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of ways to do this. This uses absolute positioning for the inner circle.

```css
.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;

  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  /* or 50% */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* or 50% */

  background-color: #d2e4ff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.outer-circle {
  display: block;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: relative;

  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  /* or 50% */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* or 50% */

  background-color: #e7f1ff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row" class="h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-2 h-100">
          <span class="outer-circle mx-auto my-auto">
            <span class="inner-circle mx-auto my-auto">
              <img src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/tropical-blue/stackoverflow-6-xxl.png" height="40" width="40" />
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 my-auto">
          <h4 class="display5">Cool stuff</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```